# Button inside updatePanel doesn't works after downloading

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, download

In my application I have updatepanel with few buttons. One of those button is 'Export' button - after clicking it user can download report to his local computer.

button is created in this way:

```
btnSave = new Button
 { ID = "btnSave", CausesValidation = false, Text = "Save", CommandName = CommandNames.SaveToCSV };
Controls.Add(btnSave);
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btnSave);
```

And after clicking it this code is executed:

```
string csv = GenerateReport();
Page.Response.Clear();
Page.Response.Buffer = true;
Page.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
Page.Response.Write(csv);
Page.Response.End();
```

Downloading works corectly even in update panel. My problem is that after first click on Export button all buttons stop works - I have page that doesn't send anything to server - checked in Fiddler (but client javascrpts works correctly).
Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? Maybe there is another way of downloading data from updatepanel (I cannot remove this button from update panel).

Comment: Did you try my answer (what are the response contents in fiddler after your async button is clicked)? I'm interested to know what the problem was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this happens, but a quick workaround could be to change the download button to a simple href with target=_blank, and move the csv generation code to a dedicated page\http-handler

Answer (score 0):

The UpdatePanel expects a valid delta after the async postback, but you're sending a CSV file. My guess is that an exception is silently being thrown, but you don't see a yellow screen because of partial postback. Does Fiddler show a response that looks like a yellow screen (look at the response contents in Fiddler)?

(user4537's workaround would work because it avoids the problem I describe above.)